# Implementation of BFS using queue and adjacency list in C

Tags: c, graph, queue, breadth-first-search

I was solving a problem which allowed two types of operations: subtracting one from a number or multiplying it by two, with the source and the destination numbers provided. Input constraints are 1<=n<=10^4 for both numbers. I'm supposed to output the number of operations needed to produce the desired number from the given one. The following is my implementation, getting runtime error and, obviously, I do not know why. It'll be awesome if someone explains the bug. Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int g[22222][3], v[2222], size;//g == graph, v == visited and size == the size of queue
typedef struct _queue
{
    int val;
    struct _queue *next;
    struct _queue *prev;
} queue;
queue *head=NULL, *last=NULL;
void push(int val)
{
    queue *ptr=(queue *) malloc(sizeof(queue));
    ptr->next=NULL;
    ptr->val=val;
    if (head)
    {
        last->next=ptr;
        ptr->prev=last;
    }
    else
    {
        head=ptr;
        ptr->prev=NULL;
    }
    last=ptr;
}
void pop()
{
    if (size)
    {
        queue *ptr=last;
        last=last->prev;
        if (head) last->next=NULL;
        free(ptr);
    }
}
int front() {return last->val;}
int bfs(int s, int d)//s == source and d == destination
{
    int cnt=0;
    push(s);
    size++;
    v[s]=1;
    while (size)
    {
        int u=front();
        pop();
        size--;
        for (int j=1; j<=2; j++)
        {
            if (d==g[u][j]) return (cnt+1);
            if (!v[g[u][j]])
            {
                v[g[u][j]]=1;
                size++;
                push(g[u][j]);
            }
        }
        cnt++;
    }
}
int main()
{
    int n, m, val;
    scanf("%d%d", &n, &m);
    if (n==m) {printf("0"); return 0;}
    val=(n>m?n:m)*2;
    v[0]=1;
    for (int i=1; i<=val; i++)
    {
        g[i][1]=2*i;
        g[i][2]=i-1;
    }
    printf("%d", bfs(n, m));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have implemented a stack i.e. LIFO (last in first out): you are adding to the end and retrieving from the end.

You should implement a queue i.e. FIFO (first in first out), so if you add to end, you should retrieve from front:

```
void pop()
{
    if (size)
    {
        queue *ptr=head;
        head=head->next;
        if (head) head->prev=NULL;
        free(ptr);
    }
}
int front() 
{
   return head->val;
}
```

Also, I guess your aim is to count the *smallest* number of operations required to produce the desired number from a given one. Your `cnt` variable does not represent the smallest number of operations, it represents the number of times you retrieved an element from the queue. You need to increment it for each *new level* instead.

Finally, your `bfs` should return a value even if there is no path from `s` to `d`, so you should put `return 0;` after the `while(size){}` loop.

UPD. You need to skip `g[u][j]` if it is larger than `2 * (10^4)` inside of `bfs`, otherwise those values be enqueued which is a waste of space. By the way your `v` array has only 2222 elements, it should have at least 20001 (`v[20000]` is the last one)